# Issue with file managerin Angular app - fole and folders not visible

Tags: angular, typescript

I finally implemented file manager from [this](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-explorer-component/#conclucion) tutorial.
I don't have any errors in vscode and chrome debug tool, somebody can tell me why my folders are not visible?

[image]

I have no idea how to fix it. I will give you everything you need :)

## Update 1

I think the issue is with importing styles from outside. I just only created index.html and style.scss - this need to be connected somehow?

[image]

Index.html :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Styles.html:

@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

## Update 2

I adding mp-file-explorer.component files:

*.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MpFileElement } from '../../models/mp-file-element.model';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MpNewFolderDialogComponent } from '../messages/mp-new-folder-dialog/mp-new-folder-dialog.component';
import { MpRenameDialogComponent } from '../messages/mp-rename-dialog/mp-rename-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-mp-file-explorer',
  templateUrl: './mp-file-explorer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mp-file-explorer.component.scss']
})
export class MpFileExplorerComponent {

  @Input() fileElements: MpFileElement[] = [
    {
      id: '',
      isFolder: false,
      name: '',
      parent: ''
    }
  ];
  @Input() canNavigateUp = '';
  @Input() path = '';

  @Output() folderAdded = new EventEmitter<{ name: string}>();
  @Output() elementRemoved = new EventEmitter<MpFileElement>();
  @Output() elementRenamed = new EventEmitter<MpFileElement>();
  @Output() elementMoved = new EventEmitter<{
    element: MpFileElement,
    moveTo: MpFileElement
  }>();
  @Output() navigatedDown = new EventEmitter<MpFileElement>();
  @Output() navigatedUp = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  deleteElement(element: MpFileElement) {
    this.elementRemoved.emit(element);
  }

  navigate(element: MpFileElement) {
    if (element.isFolder) {
      this.navigatedDown.emit();
    }
  }

  navigateUp() {
    this.navigatedUp.emit();
  }

  moveElement(element: MpFileElement, moveTo: MpFileElement) {
    this.elementMoved.emit({
      element,
      moveTo
    });
  }

  openNewFolderDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MpNewFolderDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.folderAdded.emit({ name: res });
      }
    });
  }

  openRenameDialog(element: MpFileElement) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MpRenameDialogComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        element.name = res;
        this.elementRenamed.emit(element);
      }
    });
  }

  openMenu(event: MouseEvent, element: MpFileElement, viewChild: MatMenuTrigger) {
    event.preventDefault();
    viewChild.openMenu();
  }
}
```

*.html:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-icon *ngIf="canNavigateUp" class="pointer" (click)="navigateUp()">
    arrow_back
  </mat-icon>
  <span style="margin-left: 8px"> {{path || 'Files'}} </span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <mat-icon class="pointer" (click)="openNewFolderDialog()">
    create_new_folder
  </mat-icon>
</mat-toolbar>

<div
  class="container"
  fxFlex
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch"
>
    <div class="content" fxFlex fxLayout="row">
      <mat-grid-list cols="8" rowHeight="100px" fxFlex>
        <mat-grid-tile
          *ngFor="let element of fileElements"
          class="file-or-folder"
        >
          <span
            [matMenuTriggerFor]="rootMenu"
            [matMenuTriggerData]="{element: element}"
            #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"
          >
          </span>
          <div
            fxLayout="column"
            fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"
            (click)="navigate(element)"
            (contextmenu)="openMenu($event, menuTrigger)"
          >
            <mat-icon
              color="primary"
              class="file-or-folder-icon pointer"
              *ngIf="element.isFolder"
            >
              folder
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon
              color="primary"
              class="file-or-folder-icon pointer"
              *ngIf="!element.isFolder"
            >
              insert_drive_file
            </mat-icon>

            <span>{{element.name}}</span>
          </div>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </div>
  </div>

  <mat-menu #rootMenu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-element="element">
      <button
        mat-menu-item
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="moveToMenu"
        [matMenuTriggerData]="{self: element}"
      >
        <mat-icon>open_with</mat-icon>
        <span>Move To</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="openRenameDialog(element)">
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        <span>Rename</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteElement(element)">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        <span>Delete</span>
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-menu>

  <mat-menu #moveToMenu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-self="self">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let element of fileElements">
        <button
          *ngIf="element.isFolder && element.id !== self.id"
          mat-menu-item
          (click)="moveElement(self, element)"
        >
          {{element.name}}
        </button>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-menu>
```

*.scss:

```
:host {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

.file-or-folder {
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.file-or-folder-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

## Update 3

I adding more details:

```
main.component.ts

import { MatSidenav, MatGridTileHeaderCssMatStyler } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { CoreService, CoreHelper, Indicator } from 'mpcore';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MpFileElement } from 'projects/mpcore-app/lib-common/src/lib/mp-file-explorer/models/mp-file-element.model';
import { MpFileService } from 'projects/mpcore-app/lib-common/src/lib/mp-file-explorer/services/file.service';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'main-root',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MainComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  public _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  protected isInitialized = false;

  public applicationName: string;
  public selectedItems: number;
  public took: number | null = null;
  public customText: string | null = null;
  public allItems: number;
  public openCloseMenu = 'closeMenu';
  public MainIndicator: Indicator = new Indicator();

  public fileElements: Observable<MpFileElement[]> = new Observable<MpFileElement[]>();

  currentRoot!: MpFileElement;
  currentPath!: string;
  canNavigateUp!: boolean;

  @ViewChild('sidenav', { static: false }) sidenav: MatSidenav | null = null;
  public constructor(

    private coreService: CoreService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private fileService: MpFileService
    ) {
    this.canNavigateUp = false;
    this.isInitialized = true;
    this.coreService.applicationName = this.applicationName = 'file-manager';
    this.allItems = 0;
    this.selectedItems = 0;
    this.coreService.langChanged$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.translate.use(this.coreService.lang);
      });

    this.coreService.showUserPanel$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          (this.sidenav as MatSidenav).open();
        } else {
          (this.sidenav as MatSidenav).close();
        }
      });

    this.coreService.displayAllItems$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.allItems = data;
      });

    this.coreService.displaySelectedItems$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.selectedItems = data;
      });

    this.coreService.displayTook$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.took = data;
      });

    this.coreService.displayCustomText$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.customText = data;
      });

    this.coreService.showModulePanel$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (this.openCloseMenu === 'openMenu') {
          this.openCloseMenu = 'closeMenu';
        } else {
          this.openCloseMenu = 'openMenu';
        }
      });

    this.coreService.showIndicator$
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.isInitialized),
        takeUntil(this._onDestroy)
      )
      .subscribe((message) => {
        if (CoreHelper.hasValue(message)) {
          this.MainIndicator.ShowBusy(message);
        } else {
          this.MainIndicator.HideBusy();
        }
      });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isInitialized = false;
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }

  public openCoreModuleList() {
    if (this.openCloseMenu === 'openMenu') {
      this.openCloseMenu = 'closeMenu';
    } else {
      this.openCloseMenu = 'openMenu';
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const folderA = this.fileService.add({ name: 'Folder A', isFolder: true, parent: 'root' });

    if ( folderA.id !== undefined ) {
      this.fileService.add({ name: 'Folder B', isFolder: true, parent: 'root' });
      this.fileService.add({ name: 'Folder C', isFolder: true, parent: folderA.id });
      this.fileService.add({ name: 'File A', isFolder: false, parent: 'root' });
      this.fileService.add({ name: 'File B', isFolder: false, parent: 'root' });
    }

    this.updateFileElementQuery();
  }

  addFolder(folder: { name: string }) {
    if ( this.currentRoot !== undefined && this.currentRoot.id ) {
      this.fileService.add({ isFolder: true, name: folder.name, parent: this.currentRoot ? this.currentRoot.id : 'root' });
    }

    this.updateFileElementQuery();
  }

  removeElement(element: MpFileElement) {
    if ( element.id !== undefined ) {
      this.fileService.delete(element.id);
    }
    this.updateFileElementQuery();
  }

  moveElement(event: { element: MpFileElement; moveTo: MpFileElement }) {
    if ( event.element.id !== undefined ) {
      this.fileService.update(event.element.id, { parent: event.moveTo.id });
    }
    this.updateFileElementQuery();
  }

  renameElement(element: MpFileElement) {
    if ( element.id !== undefined ) {
      this.fileService.update(element.id, { name: element.name });
    }
    this.updateFileElementQuery();
  }

  updateFileElementQuery() {
    if ( this.currentRoot !== undefined && this.currentRoot.id ) {
      this.fileElements = this.fileService.queryInFolder(this.currentRoot ? this.currentRoot.id : 'root');
    }
  }

  navigateUp() {
    if (this.currentRoot && this.currentRoot.parent === 'root') {
      this.currentRoot.name = 'root';
      this.canNavigateUp = false;
      this.updateFileElementQuery();
    } else {
      if ( this.currentRoot.parent !== undefined ) {
        const currentRootTemp = this.fileService.get(this.currentRoot.parent);
        if (currentRootTemp !== undefined) {
          this.currentRoot = currentRootTemp;
        }
      }
      this.updateFileElementQuery();
    }
    this.currentPath = this.popFromPath(this.currentPath);
  }

  navigateToFolder(element: MpFileElement) {
    this.currentRoot = element;
    this.updateFileElementQuery();
    if ( element.name !== undefined ) {
      this.currentPath = this.pushToPath(this.currentPath, element.name);
    }
    this.canNavigateUp = true;
  }

  pushToPath(path: string, folderName: string) {
    let p = path ? path : '';
    p += `${folderName}/`;
    return p;
  }

  popFromPath(path: string) {
    let p = path ? path : '';
    const split = p.split('/');
    split.splice(split.length - 2, 1);
    p = split.join('/');
    return p;
  }
}
```

Main.component.html:

```
<div class="full-height fxcol" [ngClass]="'side-menu-disabled'">
  <core-top-panel [applicationName]="applicationName"></core-top-panel>
  <div class="fxgrow">
    <div class="core-main-window fxgrow fxcol">
      <mat-sidenav-container class="fxfill">
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav position="end" mode="over">
          <core-user-panel></core-user-panel>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mp-indicator [indicator]="MainIndicator"></mp-indicator>

        <div class="full-height fxcol">
          <div style="padding: 100px; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <mat-card style="height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding:0">
              <lib-mp-file-explorer [fileElements]="fileElements | async" [path]="currentPath" [canNavigateUp]="canNavigateUp" (folderAdded)="addFolder($event)"
                (elementRemoved)="removeElement($event)" (navigatedDown)="navigateToFolder($event)" (navigatedUp)="navigateUp()" (elementRenamed)="renameElement($event)"
                (elementMoved)="moveElement($event)">
              </lib-mp-file-explorer>
            </mat-card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav-container>
      <core-footer [allItems]="allItems" [selectedItems]="selectedItems" [took]="took" [customText]="customText"> </core-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Update 4

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { v4 } from 'uuid';
import { MpFileElement } from '../models/mp-file-element.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { NullTemplateVisitor } from '@angular/compiler';

export interface IFileService {
    add(fileElement: MpFileElement): MpFileElement;
    delete(id: string): void;
    update(id: string, update: Partial<MpFileElement>): void;
    queryInFolder(folderId: string): Observable<MpFileElement[]>;
    get(id: string): MpFileElement | void;
}

@Injectable()
export class MpFileService implements IFileService {

    constructor() {}
    private map = new Map<string, MpFileElement>()

    private querySubject: BehaviorSubject<MpFileElement[]> = new BehaviorSubject<MpFileElement[]>([]);

    add(fileElement: MpFileElement): MpFileElement {
        fileElement.id = v4();
        this.map.set(fileElement.id, this.clone(fileElement));
        return fileElement;
    }

    delete(id: string): void {
        this.map.delete(id);
    }

    update(id: string, update: Partial<MpFileElement>): void {
        let element = this.map.get(id);
        element = Object.assign(element, update);
        if ( element.id !== undefined ) {
            this.map.set(element.id, element);
        }
    }
    queryInFolder(folderId: string): Observable<MpFileElement[]> {
        const result: MpFileElement[] = [];
        this.map.forEach(element => {
            if (element.parent === folderId) {
                result.push(this.clone(element));
            }
        });
        if (!this.querySubject) {
            this.querySubject = new BehaviorSubject(result);
        } else {
            this.querySubject.next(result);
        }
        return this.querySubject.asObservable();
    }

    get(id: string): MpFileElement | undefined {
        if ( id !== undefined ) {
            return this.map.get(id);
        }
        return undefined;
    }

    clone(element: MpFileElement): MpFileElement {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're gonna need to post at all relevant code, with the irrelevant stuff left out.

Comment: There is a lot of code, the whole app is really big, how i can do it if i don't wanna post every part of app? I think the issue is with index.html and styles.scss. I post a screenshot of my tree. I trying to add that files but im not sure i doing it correctly (file manager is as library, not module).

Comment: I'd start off with the html for the component we can see in your image, and the bit of typescript that contains the data for the html.

Comment: The problem with your link is that it's a long article that nobody is going to take the time to read through and ask you questions about where you might have done something differently.

Comment: I add some details, maybe somebody know that i did wrong? I think there is something bad.

Comment: I would say that the issue is not with the styles (clearly some styles are working!). Surely the issue is that you would expect to see content, but it's not visible. This is not related to style imports.

Comment: Ok, i start from component, give me a sec.

Comment: Nobody has idea whats going on?

Comment: Guys i really need help. Outside my project it working pretty fine. I checked it 5 times and i have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: The code you have provided is both too much and not enough. I don't think the css is relevant, and you haven't posted any code for the parent that is setting `@Input() fileElements`

Answer (score 0):

The file list in the html is binding to

```
@Input() fileElements: MpFileElement[] = [
    {
      id: '',
      isFolder: false,
      name: '',
      parent: ''
    }
  ];
```

This is an `@Input()` property, which means that it can be set by the parent component. It is a little odd that it is also being assigned to an almost empty array.

You haven't posted the parent component, so it's hard to see why @fileElements has no content.

Edit:

OK, now you've posted your parent component, it's easy to see why you're having issues.

Firstly, I would move all of the code from the body of your constructor into `ngOnInit()`. In components, the constructor should really only be used for injecting your dependencies. `ngOnInit()` is where the heavy initialisation should take place.

Secondly, the fileElements is only set in `updateFileElementsQuery`. I can't see where `this.currentRoot` is set before this method is called, so `this.fileElements` is not going to be set due to the false statement in the guard clause:

```
updateFileElementQuery() {
    if ( this.currentRoot !== undefined && this.currentRoot.id ) {
      this.fileElements = this.fileService.queryInFolder(this.currentRoot ? this.currentRoot.id : 'root');
    }
  }
```

Try putting a console.log(this.currentRoot) at the start of this method to see if this is the case.

I have created an extremely simple stackblitz to demonstrate the general order of events here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5nmru. This doesn't have any of the interactive functionality you're after, but it sets up the initial file system, sets the current root, and then sets up the query.

Comment: Ok, i added Update 3 with main component. Trying add some elements in input as predefined but it didn't work.

Comment: I've edited my answer. The most problematic issue is that the current root isn't set the first time you are updating the fileElements property.

Comment: Sadly, whole code inside constructor are implemented before this functionality, there is nothing to move. At the second, how i can init it properly? It's true, root is undefined.

Comment: I'm not sure why the constructor code can't be moved to ngOnInit(). At the very least you should be able to move it before the code that's already there. You need to set the current root early on, before you start doing any of the other processing. And because you're using observables, you need to make sure that any dependencies are set first. This might be something like `fileService.getRoot().subscribe(root => { this.currentRoot = root; this.updateFileElementQuery(); })`

Comment: My service dont have method get root. Updating post (see update 4).

Comment: No, I was obviously guessing at that.

Comment: So your "file system" is built in ngOnInit() using the add() service method. And you're calling the service from the constructor before the file system has been built. The order of code in ngOnInit() (with **nothing** in the constructor) should be 1. build file system like now. 2. Set current root - looks like it should be `'root'`. 3. run code that is currently in constructor.

Comment: Ok, but in mp-file-exploer i din't have anything in constructor except public dialog as MatDialog. In main i don't have any constructors, only in view child is one not related to my file manager. I still don't have any idea what i need to do. Trying set to root but nothing happend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207521/discussion-between-xavn-mpt-and-kurt-hamilton).